# Following a path in LibGdx

Tags: java, libgdx, artificial-intelligence, path-finding

I've got code that's outputting a path in libGdx:

```
public Target(Vector2 villager, Vector2 target){
      pathFinder = new IndexedAStarPathFinder<Node>(LevelManager.graph, false);

        int startX = (int) villager.x;
        int startY = (int) villager.y;

        int endX = (int) target.x;
        int endY = (int) target.y;

        Node startNode = LevelManager.graph.getNodeByXY(startX, startY);
        Node endNode = LevelManager.graph.getNodeByXY(endX, endY);

        pathFinder.searchNodePath(startNode, endNode, new HeuristicImp(), resultPath);
        Gdx.app.log("Path", ""+ resultPath.getCount());

  }
```

My question is, is there a way of then using the resultPath to implement movement without using steering behaviors? Something simple to grasp and implement? I'm talking about moving the x and y of a sprite in accordance to the outputted path. Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to move your sprite from it's `currentPosition` to the `nextPosition` - you can store these values in [Vector2](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector2.html) class instances.

You will be updateing sprite's position in your `render()` method like

```
    Vector2 currentPosition, nextPosition;
    final float SPEED; //how fast sprite will be moved

    //render()
    Vector2 step = nextPosition.cpy().sub(currentPosition).nor().scl(SPEED);
    sprite.setPosition(sprite.getX() + step.x, sprite.getY() + step.y);
```

then you have to check whether your sprite achieved nextPosition (or rather if it's distance of it is small enough) and if yes you must set new `nextPosition` value

```
    if(nextPosition.cpy().sub(sprite.getX(), sprite.getY()).len() < SOME_LENGTH) {
        nextPosition = getNextPosition();
```

If no new `nextPosition` is to get then the new `nextPosition` value should be just sprite's position (to keep it in place)

Comment: Where does the resultPath come in? Do you loop through as the connections are added? Or do you somehow interpret the whole path? I don't get how the path translates into the nextPosition.

Comment: As the `nextPosition` you should keep only next node of path - whole path should be kept in some another variable

Comment: Any hints towards where the Node to Vector2 translation happens?

Comment: Node has to have `x` and `y` coordinate's kept somewhere so all you need is to get node's position - that's your vector